# WPF Application same size at every system scale (scale independent)

Tags: c#, wpf, scale, dpi

Is there any way to make WPF application get same size at every system scale?

When I change **Change size of text, apps and other items** in windows system setting from **125% (Recommended)** to **100%** in a Full-HD screen, My WPF application gets too small. To implement independent system scale application I've wrote a function like this to change scaling of my app back to 125%:

```
private void ScaleTo125Percents()
{
    // Change scale of window content
    MainContainer.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(1.25, 1.25, 0, 0);
    Width *= 1.25;
    Height *= 1.25;

    // Bring window center screen
    var screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    var screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    Top  = ( screenHeight - Height ) / 2;
    Left = ( screenWidth  - Width )  / 2;
}
```

But there are conditions to call this function. First of the screen must be Full-HD (There are APIs to check this) and also system scale must be 100% (There is no .NET API to get system scale).

What can I do? Am I doing standard way to make my application system scale independent?

Example of scale independent applications I've seen:

- *Visual Studio 2017 Installer*
- *Telegram Desktop*

Comment: Check out the `Viewbox` layout container: https://blog.udemy.com/wpf-viewbox/

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are asking for when you say "scale independent" then.  `Viewbox` can give you a canvas of a specific virtual size.  Everything placed in it will display and be laid out as if it the `Viewbox` was always the specified size, regardless of the application's window size, or the systems DPI.  Maybe a drawing of how your content behaves at different sizes would help.

Comment: It is of course possible to get information about the current screen resolution and infer a scaling that will allow you to achieve a "constant" display size (in quotes, because monitor dot pitch varies, often in ways not reportable to a program). The problem is that you're trying to do something that you shouldn't be doing. The system-wide scaling setting is intended for the **user** to use, and is intended to have exactly the effect you are trying to prevent. If you want your program to appear larger, set the system-wide setting larger. Don't add code that competes with the user.

Comment: _"When application gets to small that user can't see it in 100% scale mode, it's programmer's duty to fix it!"_ -- I disagree. The reason that scaling mode exists in Windows in the first place is that _all_ programs wind up unreadable if they simply render at a fixed pixel size regardless of the monitor's dot pitch. ...

Comment: ... If you want to provide an additional _user setting_ in your program to further refine scaling, that's fine, but doing that doesn't require knowing what the system-wide setting is, never mind any attempt to offset it. But you should otherwise assume the user has the system-wide value set as desired for a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found an answer. First get system DPI scale using one of the options below:

- Read from registry `AppliedDPI` dword located in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`. Then divide it by 96.
- Or use this snippet:

  ```
  double dpiFactor = System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
  ```

  that returns a value between 1.0 to 2.5

Then create a config file that holds application settings and set dpiFactor as default scale. If user preferred a custom scale, call this function on window startup:

```
private void UserInterfaceCustomScale(double customScale)
{
    // Change scale of window content
    MainContainer.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(customScale, customScale, 0, 0);
    Width *= customScale;
    Height *= customScale;

    // Bring window center screen
    var screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    var screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    Top  = ( screenHeight - Height ) / 2;
    Left = ( screenWidth  - Width )  / 2;
}
```